# How to sort categories by id in wordpress admin

Tags: categories, admin

I would like to know if it is possible in Wordpress admin to show categories in `post-new.php` and `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category` sorted by id NOT by category name.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work...

```
add_action('get_terms_args','my_order_cats',10,2);
function my_order_cats($args,$taxonomies){
    //Check we are admin side
    if(is_admin()){
        $taxonomy = $taxonomies[0]; 
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        //Check screen ID and taxonomy and changes $args where appropriate. 
        if(($screen->id=='edit-category'||$screen->id=='post') && $taxonomy=='category'){
            $args['orderby']='id'; //preserves order of subcategories.
            $args['order']='asc'; //or desc
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```

It preserves the order of subcategories (i.e. children always appear below their parents regarldless if order is set to ASC/DESC).

This could be adapted for custom taxonomies, you would simply need to chhange the `$screen->ID` and `$taxonomy` checks.

Comment: I think I would do the `if( is_admin() )` on the `add_action()`...it seems slightly more efficient, just a thought. Good solution though :)

Comment: I tried the above solution and it wordks in the taxonomy page. But it doesn't work in the add new post page, and the category box at the right sidebar. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry missed that! All you need to check the screen ID. I'll update my answer. However, it would work for new posts and editing old posts - is that a problem? You can probably make it apply to only new posts though...

Comment: @m0r7if3r yeah probably, but I've always kept the logic inside hooked functions - aesthetics more than anything :D.

Comment: @StephenHarris I'm pretty concerned with performance...probably too concerned with performance at times :D